# Why is "default + label" pseudo-class on "input" element not working? In particular the "+ label" part

Tags: html

":default" alone is working, but when you add the "label" on the pseudo-class, it doesn't work.

```css
.pseudo-test input:default {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 20px red;
}

.pseudo-test input:default+label {
  color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:200px" class="pseudo-test">

  <form action="another-action.php">


    <label for="summer">Select your gender:</label>
    <input type="radio" id="summer" name="radio-selection" value="value-of-a-radio" checked>
    <button>Press to submit</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

":default" only works, but when you add "label" by typing "default + label", it doesn't work. The pseudo-class should apply to the label of the input, but it's not working.

Comment: `+` is used to select the adjacent sibling. You can't select previous siblings with CSS.

Comment: `+` is the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), and selects the element *after* another element. *"The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent"*

Comment: When then why it's given as an example in the developers.mozilla.org for learners of HTML? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:default

Comment: In the examples you point to, all the labels follow the input they belong to, not precede. Your example is the opposite

Comment: You're right. I just moved the label element below the input element, and now it works. I had no idea it works this way, or that it makes such big difference which element comes first.

Comment: The devil is in the details

Comment: Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) is used to select the adjacent sibling appearing immediately after in the markup; you can't select previous siblings with CSS. However, you can achieve a similar effect by placing the label directly after the input and floating it to the left.

```css
.pseudo-test input:default {
    box-shadow:0 0 20px 20px red;
    }
    
    
.pseudo-test input:default + label {
  color: coral;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:200px" class="pseudo-test">

        <form action="another-action.php">
        
        
            
            <input type="radio" id="summer" name="radio-selection" value="value-of-a-radio" checked>
            <label for="summer">Select your gender:</label>
            <button>Press to submit</button>
            
        </form>
    
    </div>
```